# problem with converting from pixel to lat/lon

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am using the fromPixels() function in osmdroid (3.05) like so:

```
public boolean onScroll(ScrollEvent e) {

    //get the scroll's destination
    GeoPoint g = (GeoPoint) e.getSource().getProjection().fromPixels(e.getX(), e.getY());
    Toast.makeText(e.getSource().getContext(), "in e6: " +
    g.getLongitudeE6() + " " + g.getLatitudeE6() + " in deg's" + 
    convertToDecimalDegrees(g.getLongitudeE6())
    + " " + convertToDecimalDegrees(g.getLatitudeE6()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
```

I am scrolling the map somewhere near -0.0029109 51.9933734 but in the toast i get:
-0.9613029999999999 76.60554499999999 so it seems like the lat is way off (the convert to decimal
degrees is Ok - i just multiply by 1E-6)
Am i using the function incorrectly?
From what i read it seems like my usage is fine, also i read that there used to be a problem with
that function but that it should be fixed now

Thanks in advance!
Omri

Comment: This thread is very similar with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898313/limit-scrolling-on-offline-maps-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this thread is a little old but the answer to this question can be found on http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=209
To point is to set max extent of map and restrict scrolling to that extent. 
Below is the summary of issue mentioned above (Add the code below to MapView.java)

```java
protected Rect mScrollableAreaLimit = null;

public void setScrollableAreaLimit(BoundingBoxE6 boundingBox) {  
    final int worldSize_2 =  TileSystem.MapSize(MapViewConstants.MAXIMUM_ZOOMLEVEL) / 2;
    // Clear scrollable area limit if null passed.
    if (boundingBox == null) {
        mScrollableAreaLimit = null;
        return;
    }

    // Get NW/upper-left
    final Point upperLeft = TileSystem.LatLongToPixelXY(boundingBox.getLatNorthE6() / 1E6,
            boundingBox.getLonWestE6() / 1E6, MapViewConstants.MAXIMUM_ZOOMLEVEL, null);
    upperLeft.offset(-worldSize_2, -worldSize_2);

    // Get SE/lower-right
    final Point lowerRight = TileSystem.LatLongToPixelXY(boundingBox.getLatSouthE6() / 1E6,
            boundingBox.getLonEastE6() / 1E6, MapViewConstants.MAXIMUM_ZOOMLEVEL, null);
    lowerRight.offset(-worldSize_2, -worldSize_2);
    mScrollableAreaLimit = new Rect(upperLeft.x, upperLeft.y, lowerRight.x, lowerRight.y);
}
```

Now you can call the setScrollableAreaLimit method when map view is created or you can expand constructor with BoundingBoxE6 parameter.

Hope this helps.

In addition to this a correction for double tap bug is needed http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=209#c23

```
@Override
public void computeScroll() {
    if (mScroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
        if (mScroller.isFinished()) {
            // This will facilitate snapping-to any Snappable points.
            setZoomLevel(mZoomLevel);
        } else {
            /* correction for double tap */
            int targetZoomLevel = getZoomLevel();
            if (targetZoomLevel == mZoomLevel)
                scrollTo(mScroller.getCurrX(), mScroller.getCurrY());
        }
        postInvalidate(); // Keep on drawing until the animation has
        // finished.
    }
}
```

Comment: Only seen this now, Thanks A lot! i will give it a try.