# how to set maximum zoom level for offline maps?

Tags: java, android, zooming, offline, osmdroid

Basically I have an offline maps from Google Maps. I downloaded it from MOBAC and successfully display the offline map but the maximum level is limited to 18, and the offline map is capable of 19 zooms. I am using osmdroid library and Android. How do I program this such a way that  it will enable 19 zoom-in? please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know about android but in google maps api v3 the map object has setting `maxZoom` for this... If it's nonsense for android just drop a comment, I'll delete this answer.

Comment: I believe your answer is not what I need, thanks for answering though...^^

Comment: Sir,I have a question, how do I increase the my question's visibility to experts? Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898313/limit-scrolling-on-offline-maps-in-android

Comment: @rahstame, you can look at the FAQ (there is something on how to ask good questions), as on meta.stackoverflow.com (they will help you about it), or ask moderators (by flagging) to move the question to android.stackexchange.com